# Compute the local max/min for a given X Y series

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have an array consist of `Point2D` ( which has two members, `x` and `y`), e.g., `Point2D[] points`. You cna think of this array as a series of points on a X Y graph. The array is sorted in such a way that it is arranged from the smaller `Point2D.X` to the bigger `Point2D.X`

My question is simple: how do you find the points ( and the corresponding item index right before and after those points) that are the local maxima/minima? Recall that local max/min is defined mathematically as `dy/dx=0`. So my task is that I would need to find the those points where `dy/dx=0`.

**Please note that the the extreme points may or may not located right inside the `Point2D` array, as the graph is a smooth curve, not an linearly-piece-wise polyline. An extreme point can be the middle point of two points inside the array. for instance.**

Is there any existing libraries/ components that already do this in C#?

Here is my method:

```
public class Point2D
{
  public double X;
  public double Y;
}

public class PointWithIndex
{
  // the extreme point where dy/dx=0
  public Point2D ExtremePoints;
  // the index of the array for the point that locates right before this ExtremePoints
  public int PrevItemIndex;

}

public static List<PointWithIndex> FindLocalExtrema(List<Point2D> xyPoints)
{
  // the algorithm to find the max/min points of xyPoints
}
```

Comment: You are looking for a "peak detector".

Comment: It depends on the form of the smooth function that you've used to interpolate your data...

Comment: @DarrenEngwirda, indeed. But first I don't know how to define the smooth function in a robust way. Second, I don't know how to get from the smooth function to its derivative function beyond doing something like symbolic computing which is not really available in C#.

Comment: @Graviton: Ok, so probably your question should actually be about finding interpolating functions for your data. Curve fitting is a huge topic, and the "best" approach almost always depends on the specifics of your data. Some kind of spline fit is often a good place to start...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest running a loop 0 < i < n - 1, check if P[i - 1].Y < P[i].Y && P[i + 1].Y < P[i].Y, then P[i] is a max. do the same with min.

Comment: The extreme points may or may not located right inside the Point2D array, as the graph is a smooth curve, not an linearly-piece-wise polyline. An extreme point can be the middle point of two points inside the array. for instance. So I afraid things are not so simple here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for: [The Catmull-Rom Spline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catmull-Rom_spline#Catmull.E2.80.93Rom_spline) which you can easily compute using the XNA Framework (in C#) as shown [here](http://glasnost.itcarlow.ie/~powerk/xna/Catmulroml.html).

The idea is: you will generate -iteratively or recursively- points using Catmull-Rom until you hit your local maxima.